# VB.Net - Remove empty items in ListBox

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I want to remove empty items from my listbox that looks something like this:

```
book1
book2

book3

book4
book5
```

And so on..

I have tried this code:

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
        Do While (ListBox1.Items.Count) - 1 >= i
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(ListBox1.Items(i)) Then
                ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.Items(i))
                i -= 1
            End If
            i += 1
        Loop
```

And i don't know why it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any type of loop for any purpose but each type is best suited to certain situations and a `Do While` loop is a poor choice in this case.  The best option in this case is to use a `For` loop and count backwards:

```
For i = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(CStr(ListBox1.Items(i))) Then
        ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i)
    End If
Next
```